# How to select group nodes by substring in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this source xml

```
<TestRun>
  <Results>
    <UnitTestResult testId="1f32f6b9-6623-1321-32b5-b2e84ef44f61" testName="TestMethod1" outcome="Passed">
      <Output>
        <TextMessages>
          <Message>__OWNER__='Team-2' some other stuff1</Message>
        </TextMessages>
      </Output>
    </UnitTestResult>
    <UnitTestResult testId="1f32f6b9-6623-1321-32b5-b2e84ef44f62" testName="TestMethod2" outcome="Failed">
      <Output>
        <TextMessages>
          <Message>__OWNER__='Team-1' some other stuff2</Message>
        </TextMessages>
      </Output>
    </UnitTestResult>
    <UnitTestResult testId="1f32f6b9-6623-1321-32b5-b2e84ef44f63" testName="TestMethod3" outcome="Failed">
      <Output>
        <TextMessages>
          <Message>__OWNER__='Team-1' some other stuff 3</Message>
        </TextMessages>
      </Output>
    </UnitTestResult>
    <UnitTestResult testId="1f32f6b9-6623-1321-32b5-b2e84ef44f64" testName="TestMethod4" outcome="Failed">
      <Output>
        <TextMessages>
          <Message>__OWNER__='Team-2' some other stuff 4</Message>
        </TextMessages>
      </Output>
    </UnitTestResult>
  </Results>
</TestRun>
```

And I need to group failed tests by owner which is a substring of Message node.

So the outcome should be

```
<TestResults>
  <Owner name="Team-1">
    <TestMethod name="TestMethod2"/>
    <TestMethod name="TestMethod3"/>
  </Owner>
  <Owner name="Team-2">
    <TestMethod name="TestMethod4"/>
  </Owner>
```

Any ideas how to achieve this (using XSLT 1.0 preferably)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to group elements in xsl1.0 and 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584767/how-to-group-elements-in-xsl1-0-and-2-0)

Comment: Not sure it's absolute duplicate as it is clear how to group by some tag value or attribute but not grouping by substring. Of course, we can google "substring" and "grouping" and then combine them together. But stackoverflow is the place that helps you to do such things in right way.

Answer (score 1):

For grouping in XSLT 1.0 see:
http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

--

***edited in response to your edit:***

To group by a substring, you can define your key as:

```
<xsl:key name="result" match="UnitTestResult" use="substring-before(substring-after(Output/TextMessages/Message, $apos), $apos)" />
```

where $apos is defined as:

```
<xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Yep, it's clear for the key. But what should be defined for for-each selector?

Comment: @Pashec That's explained in the article I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Draft version I've got for team names quoted in double quotes (not single)
Output is not xml but plain text. However script does grouping.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:key name="owner-by-name" match="UnitTestResult[@outcome='Failed']"
           use="substring-before(substring-after(Output/TextMessages/Message,'__OWNER__=&quot;'),'&quot;')" />
  <xsl:template match="*/text()" />
  <xsl:template match="TestRun/Results">
    <xsl:for-each
      select="UnitTestResult[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('owner-by-name',substring-before(substring-after(Output/TextMessages/Message,'__OWNER__=&quot;'),'&quot;'))[1])]">
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of
        select="substring-before(substring-after(Output/TextMessages/Message,'__OWNER__=&quot;'),'&quot;')" />
      <xsl:text>&#xa;------------------------------------</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each
        select="key('owner-by-name', substring-before(substring-after(Output/TextMessages/Message,'__OWNER__=&quot;'),'&quot;'))">
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@testName" />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```